# Changing CouchDB 1.2.0 user's password via HTTP api

Tags: couchdb

I'm trying to change a user's password by saving the user document with a password field. I see in Futon that a new hash and salt are created and I can independently verify the hash and salt matches the new password

However when I try to use the new password CouchDB only responds to the old one. I have tried changing the password manually by editing the document in Futon and I get the same behaviour: the hash and salt update but CouchDB does not respond to the new password.

The only means I have found so far to change a password is with Futon's change password facility. Is it not possible to change the password via HTTP or is there a step I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Read this: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Security_Features_Overview

Likely you're trying to change admin's password.

> User documents that represent server admins do not need to have the
>   "password_sha" and "salt" attributes defined - their authentication
>   credentials are stored in the .ini configuration files.

**UPD**: You can change admin's password via `/_config` API: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Complete_HTTP_API_Reference#configuration